# Inception and Work directory of Docker

Tags: docker, tensorflow

I am using docker to run tensorflow and retrain inception module. I use the following code:

```
docker run -it \
--publish 6006:6006 \
--volume ${HOME}/tf_files:/tf_files \
--workdir /tf_files \
tensorflow/tensorflow:1.1.0 bash
```

Then I use

```
python retrain.py
bottleneck_dir=bottlenecks
how_many_training_steps=500
model_dir=inception
summaries_dir=training_summaries/basic
output_graph=retrained_graph.pb
output_labels=retrained_labels.txt
image_dir=flower_photos
```

When I run these codes, directory of flower_photos should be inside docker container. However, I want this directory to be in my home directory instead (/user/documents/flower_photos). What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [use a volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/) in order to associate a host folder to a container folder:

```
docker run -it \
...
-v /user/documents/flower_photos:/path/to/inception/flower_photos
```

That way, the inception module would find an existing folder with your host content.